# Unexpected error when making a call to Slack Analytics API

Tags: google-apps-script, https, slack-api

I'm writing an apps script whose purpose is to retrieve and analyse the data returned from the [admin.analytics.getFile](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.analytics.getFile) method.

I've successfully created and installed the application in my organisation, and have verified that my app has the scopes it needs. This is what my call returns however:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_arguments","response_metadata":{"messages":["[ERROR] missing required field: type"]}}
```

Here's my script:

```
function getData() {

var analyticsUrl = "https://slack.com/api/admin.analytics.getFile";

var analyticsOptions = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN REDACTED FOR OBVIOUS REASONS',
    'type':'member'
    },
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(analyticsUrl, analyticsOptions);

Logger.log(response);

}
```

The above error indicates that I'm not passing the 'type' parameter into my request. However I've tried including it in 'headers' and in analyticsOptions, and I get the same error both ways.

I've also made sure I'm structuring my call correctly ttbomk, httpbin returns what I'd expect.

I'm hoping this is a really easy syntactical fix, I've tried all I know!

Comment: I've also added a 'metadata' obj where I included 'type':'member', at the top level of analyticsOptions, resulting in the same error.

Comment: Have you tried passing `type` in the url, like this: `https://slack.com/api/admin.analytics.getFile?type=member`?

Comment: This worked. I changed the structure of the request to match and was able to get a successful response. Cheers!